# Restrict keyboard short-cuts in x11vnc

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

How can I restrict keyboard shortcut options in x11vnc?
for example, I want to restrict Alt+F4, Alt+x, Ctrl+Q, etc.

Is -skip_keycodes option of any help here?

Comment: client-side or server-side? If client-side, which platform? Which window manager? Please read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I would like to correct my question, thanks Denilson.

The application I want to be running will be at the server side.
The server OS is CentOS 5, running a gnome WM.

I shall allow users to interact with the application through a VNC connection and do not want the users to close, exit the application or a part of the application.

the VNC viewer will be an applet hosted on a web page.

I want to host an application on a

Comment: I guess you comment was truncated. Please, edit your own question and add as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure such shortcuts in your window manager. That way, such shortcuts won't be passed to the application, and you should be able to handle them.

But, since you seem to want an application running all the time (you want to prevent users from closing it), then it might be a good idea to write a simple script like this:

```
while true; do run_your_application ; done
```

That way, if the application crashes or is closed, it is restarted. (be careful about applications that fork themselves or detach from the terminal!)

On the other hand, if you just want a browser, you can try using the [kiosk mode from Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/). See also [kiosk software at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software).

---

*Update:* So you are using Gnome... I don't use Gnome, but a quick search at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)  gave me this answer:

> https://superuser.com/questions/132666/how-to-disable-control-alt-arrow-gnome-window-manager-control-for-redhat-linux
>
> […] all the keyboard shortcuts gnome uses are under System, Preferences, Keyboard shortcuts.

But... Are you sure you want a Gnome environment running there? Do you really want users to be able to run and configure anything from your Gnome interface? Maybe you would prefer another more minimalistic Window Manager. Which one? I'm not sure, must look what are the alternatives and try some of them. Depending on the application, it might even be possible to run it with no window manager at all.

I don't what kind of problem you are trying to solve, but maybe using a VNC applet in a webpage in order to have access to one application might not be the best solution. Of course, it depends on what is the problem and who are the users.

Comment: Thanks for your response, will you please help me in understanding the WM configuration here?

Comment: I have attempted a small test with metacity & exec <application>

This restricted the complete desktop except the application executed using the command above, Now if the user closes the application, the VNC view turns blank - This is what i want to avoid.

(Java application is written and is expected to be running, the default close/maximize/restore buttons are disabled/removed from the application's user interface)

Comment: Read my answer, at the beginning of it has a solution for what you describe.